# How to set a whitelist in web view with Android Management API

Tags: android, android-webview, android-management-api

I am using Chrome Managed Configurations to set a whitelist with this code in my policy:

```
{
    "packageName": "com.android.chrome",
    "managedConfiguration": {
        'URLBlacklist': ['*'],
        'URLWhitelist': ['chrome://*', 'google.com', 'stackoverflow.com'],
        'ForceGoogleSafeSearch': True,
        'NTPContentSuggestionsEnabled': False,
    }
}
```

Now, in the [Chrome enterprise docs](https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/?policy=URLBlacklist) it says there is a way to apply the same settings to Android Web view with the `com.android.browser:URLBlacklist` restriction, but it does not explain where I would put this in my policy.

The following code does not work:

```
{
    "packageName": "com.android.chrome",
    "managedConfiguration": {
        'com.android.browser:URLBlacklist': ['reddit.com', 'youtube.com'],
        'com.android.browser:URLWhitelist': ['stackoverflow.com', 'google.com']
    }
}
```

It shows an error in chrome://policy on the phone.

`com.android.browser` is not even a real app.

Where do I need to use this `com.android.browser:URLBlacklist` to apply restrictions to all web views on the phone?

Comment: Have you tried setting this configuration on `com.google.android.webview` instead of `com.android.chrome`?

Comment: @Fred That doesn't work. I can suggest two reasons why: 1) `com.google.android.webview` does not support managed configurations (per the Play Store for Work page). 2) Android System WebView is [disabled when Chrome is installed](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/179613/is-it-better-to-use-android-system-webview-when-not-using-chrome-as-default-brow/179615#179615), so the blacklist would have to go through Chrome

Comment: Makes sense, so the configuration needs to be applied to `com.android.chrome`. Looking at [`AwPolicyProvider.java`](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/master/android_webview/java/src/org/chromium/android_webview/policy/AwPolicyProvider.java), it seems Chrome removes the prefix before using the policy in a webview. Now it's unclear why your approach doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the blacklist/whitelist for each app individually.

For example:

```
{
    "packageName": "com.jetblue.JetBlueAndroid",
    "managedConfiguration": {
        'com.android.browser:URLBlacklist': ['*'],
        'com.android.browser:URLWhitelist': ['jetblue.com']
    }
}
```

This code blocks all domains within the JetBlue app besides for JetBlue.com

There are some things to be aware of:
1. Be careful not to block any domains the app needs to function (including login pages, etc.).
2. If an app uses a direct API to display content, not a web view, then these restrictions will not apply.

Comment: One thing that I'm still wondering: Is there a built-in way to apply the restrictions to all apps?

Comment: There is a major bug in this feature. If a user taps a link in any app which opens Chrome, the page sometimes loads even if it is meant to be blocked. Any subsequent links on that page will be blocked correctly, but this is still a serious workaround.

Comment: com.android.browser:URLBl**a**cklist is now deprecated.  [(Source.)](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/?policy=URLBlacklist)  It does not work anymore in modern versions of WebView.  You must use com.android.browser:URLBl**o**cklist instead.  Please [edit] your post.  Thank you!