# How to set a whitelist and blacklist in chrome with Android Management API

Tags: android, android-management-api

i tried evrything in this link.

[How to set a whitelist in web view with Android Management API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58773799/how-to-set-a-whitelist-in-web-view-with-android-management-api)
Below is my code on api.
Any help will be appreciate

```
    { 
        "packageName": "com.android.chrome", 
        "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED", 
        "managedConfiguration": { 
                                 "URLBLacklist": ["*"], 
                                 "URLWhitelist": ["youtube.com"] 
         }, 
         "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

your json format should be following

{
      "packageName": "com.android.chrome",
      "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
      "managed_configuration": {
        "URLBlacklist": ["*"],
        "URLWhitelist": ["https://www.youtube.com"]
      },
      "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    }

Comment: Hi appreciate your response
Which code are sahring above is work on your site try it but not work on my site.
your code work on chrome.
i am begginer in this.
did u add anything else 
please help me

Comment: what do you mean by your own site?you can allow for any app.just replace your package name instead of chrome and add list of url as your need.

Comment: {
  "screenCaptureDisabled": true,
  "cameraDisabled": true,
  "systemUpdate": {
    "type": "WINDOWED",
    "startMinutes": 120,
    "endMinutes": 240
  },
  "applications": [
    {
      "packageName": "com.android.chrome",
      "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
      "managedConfiguration": {
        "URLBLacklist": [
          "*"
        ],
        "URLWhitelist": [
          "https://www.google.com"
        ]
      },
      "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    }
  ]
}

i tried this policy
i am not able to block all url exept youtube.
Any mistake or missing.

Answer (score 0):

Managed configuration keys are key-sensitive. `URLBLacklist` should be written as `URLBlacklist`

The policy below should work:

```
            { 
                "packageName": "com.android.chrome", 
                "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED", 
                "managedConfiguration": { 
                    "URLBlacklist": ["*"], 
                    "URLWhitelist": ["youtube.com"] 
                }, 
                "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
            }
```